# Fastest way to create DataTable from List without for loop

Tags: c#, linq, datacontext, sqlbulkcopy, linqdatasource

We have a **huge** list (say **100,000**) which needs to be converted to `DataTable` for `SqlBulkcopy`.

Can you guide what could be the fastest way to do this without using for loop?
For now we are doing it like - in below code `listDos` is object list

```
using (var dataTable = new DataTable(dataTableName))
{
    dataTable.Locale = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
    var columns = new[]
        {
             new DataColumn("Id", typeof(int)),
             new DataColumn("FkId", typeof(int)),
             new DataColumn("Status", typeof(string)),
             new DataColumn("RecordFrom", typeof(DateTime))
        };

    dataTable.Columns.AddRange(columns);


    foreach (ObjectDo listDo in listDos)
    {
        var row = dataTable.NewRow();

        if (rebuildDo.Id != null) row["Id"] = rebuildDo.Id;

        if (rebuildDo.FkId!= null) row["FkId"] = rebuildDo.FkId;

        row["Status"] = rebuildDo.Status;

        row["RecordFrom"] = rebuildDo.RecordFrom;

        dataTable.Rows.Add(row);
    }

    return dataTable;
}
```

Comment: If you want linq please show a linq effort. Also the linq query will not have the syntax of a loop but it does loop (iterate) over all items..

Comment: why "without for loop"? that seems a very arbitrary restriction... since you're dealing with lots of data, it is expected that something somewhere is going to need to loop...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no problem to solve (only how to improve) and perhaps belongs on another Stack Exchange site.  Plus motives are not explained

Comment: @ScottHannen it's not the loop, it's the duplication of data that will cause problems. Especially if there are a lot of data.

Comment: @MickyD on the contrary, this is a significant concern when using SqlBulkCopy. If you have 10K items, creating a DataTable with them doubles the memory usage *and* creates a lot of temporary objects that have to be garbage collected.

Comment: why are you creating a collection of `ObjectDo` and iterating over that to create a `DataTable`? instead of this fill your `DataTable` first then no iteration will be needed.

Comment: @KhairulIslam that's already explained. The OP wants to use SqlBulkCopy, not to create a DataTable. SqlBulkCopy works with DataTables or IDataReader instances. DataTable is rather cumbersome as a generic data structure which means *avoiding* it is a good idea. The FastMember library can expose an IDataReader interface on top of any IEnumerable

Comment: @KhairulIslam most times, people don't *have* a `DataTable` - they have typed data. If the intent of the `DataTable` is just to let the list interact with `SqlBulkCopy`, then this requirement makes sense, and I would actively advocate *against* working in a `DataTable`-first model. It is 2018, after all.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Perhaps.  Question is arguably too broad; does not mention operational requirements or desired throughput; _"fastest way"_ generally never leads to answers showing actual benchmarks to back-up claims

Comment: @MickyD read the first line again. It's actually very specific. If you've actually worked with SqlBulkCopy, had to send a lot of data to the database or simply check [SqlBulkCopy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy(v=vs.110).aspx) you'd understand the issue immediatelly. It's no accident that Marc Gravel and I keep posting similar answers and comments.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I understand that and respect both you and Marc but I can't help but think this is an example of ignoring the rules when it pleases

Comment: The underlying question seems quite valid to me, perhaps it just needs to be re-worded. Especially given that the answer is 3 times faster than the OPs method, and this is probably a somewhat common problem that could help many people. Sometimes rules are made to be broken. Other times, they are just guidelines. ;)

Comment: _[Can I post questions about optimizing code on Stack Overflow?....No, it isn't the best place - though it is on-topic, there's a better place for such questions. You can take working code to Code Review - but do make sure to read their help center to see what exactly they expect from a good question.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261841/can-i-post-questions-about-optimizing-code-on-stack-overflow)_

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The fastest way would be: not to.

`SqlBulkCopy` can take an `IDataReader`. "FastMember" (on NuGet) can expose a `List<T>` as an `IDataReader`:

```
List<ObjectDo> listDos = ...
using(var bcp = new SqlBulkCopy(connection)) 
using(var reader = ObjectReader.Create(listDos,
    "Id", "FkId", "Status", "RecordFrom")) 
{ 
  bcp.DestinationTableName = "SomeTable"; 
  bcp.WriteToServer(reader); 
}
```

This is now a direct reader over the list: no duplication of all the contents.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. Tried this and it seems almost three times faster than going with SqlBulkCopy and data table.. Just for curiosity, why ObjectReader is faster?

Comment: @Oxygen possibly because it is simpler? `DataTable` has quite a lot of overhead, including the fact that it actually stores fields vertically rather than horizontally (which it does to avoid having to do lots of boxing) - so you actually get pretty poor memory locality. Note that without seeing a specific performance test: I can only speculate

Comment: @Mac. Need one more small help. I have miss match in class properties and table column names, is it mandatory that reader should match table properties? Also if table contains 10 columns, how can I create Object reader with only required 5 columns?

Comment: @Oxygen look at `bcp.ColumnMappings`. Add mapping between the desired source and destination columns.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your time and direction.